# Setting up the JavaSci in CMD

Tags: java, cmd, scilab

Peace be upon you,

Based on this [link](http://help.scilab.org/docs/5.5.0/en_US/compile_and_run_javasci_v2.html), I followed the required steps for setting up the JavaSci in Windows; but I encounter this problem

```
c:\Backups>javac -cp "C:\Program Files\scilab-5.5.0\modules\javasci\jar\org.scilab.modules.javasci.jar;C:\Program Files\scilab-5.5.0\modules\types\jar\org.scilab.modules.types.jar";. TestSciLab.java

c:\Backups>set PATH=%PATH%;"C:\Program Files\scilab-5.5.0\bin"

c:\Backups>java -cp "C:\Program Files\scilab-5.5.0\modules\javasci\jar\org.scilab.modules.javasci.jar;C:\Program Files\scilab-5.5.0\modules\types\jar\org.scilab.modules.types.jar";. TestSciLab
The native library javasci does not exist or cannot be found.
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no javasci in java.library.path
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1860)
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:845)
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1084)
    at org.scilab.modules.javasci.Call_ScilabJNI.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
    at org.scilab.modules.javasci.Call_Scilab.SetFromJavaToON(Unknown Source)
    at org.scilab.modules.javasci.Scilab.initScilab(Unknown Source)
    at org.scilab.modules.javasci.Scilab.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.scilab.modules.javasci.Scilab.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at TestSciLab.main(TestSciLab.java:7)
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: org.scilab.modules.javasci.Call_ScilabJNI.SetFromJavaToON()V
    at org.scilab.modules.javasci.Call_ScilabJNI.SetFromJavaToON(Native Method)
    at org.scilab.modules.javasci.Call_Scilab.SetFromJavaToON(Unknown Source)
    at org.scilab.modules.javasci.Scilab.initScilab(Unknown Source)
    at org.scilab.modules.javasci.Scilab.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.scilab.modules.javasci.Scilab.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at TestSciLab.main(TestSciLab.java:7)

c:\Backups>
```

The only difference that you see in the above screen and the guides in the [link](http://help.scilab.org/docs/5.5.0/en_US/compile_and_run_javasci_v2.html) is the place of %path% that I moved it to the beginning. But do not doubt! even I checked it with the reverse order and I got the error.

My code is as simple as

```
import org.scilab.modules.javasci.JavasciException.InitializationException;
import org.scilab.modules.javasci.Scilab;

public class TestSciLab {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InitializationException {
        Scilab sci = new Scilab();
    }
}
```

Any lighting up points?

Answer (score 1):

On Windows, you just need to add Scilab's bin folder to %PATH%.